# How to convert a ruby file to json?

Tags: json, ruby

I want to extract information like `Name`, `Description`, `LHOST`, `SOURCE` from the following file.

https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/blob/master/modules/auxiliary/docx/word_unc_injector.rb

Could anybody let me know how to do so robustly? One way is to convert the ruby file in to json format (then json can be processed easily). But I am sure how to convert ruby file to json? Could anybody let me know? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

The following script `rb2json0.rb` works.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'ripper'
require 'json'
puts Ripper.sexp($stdin.read).to_json()
```

```
$ ./rb2json0.rb <<< 'def hello(world) "Hello, #{world}!"; end'
["program",[["def",["@ident","hello",[1,4]],["paren",["params",[["@ident","world",[1,10]]],null,null,null,null,null,null]],["bodystmt",[["string_literal",["string_content",["@tstring_content","Hello, ",[1,18]],["string_embexpr",[["var_ref",["@ident","world",[1,27]]]]],["@tstring_content","!",[1,33]]]]],null,null,null]]]]
```