# How to extract data from JSON converted from ruby script?

Tags: json, jq

[How to convert a ruby file to json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66191457/how-to-convert-a-ruby-file-to-json)

I use the above approach (`rb2json0.rb` is in the above link) to convert a ruby script to JSON. But the JSON is not well formatted as it only has arrays but not dictionaries, making it difficult to work with the JSON output.

I specifically want to extract fields in `update_info`, e.g.,

- Name
- Description
- License
- References
- Author

and to extract the fields in `register_options`, e.g.,

- LHOST
- SOURCE
- FILENAME
- DOCAUTHOR

Note that the extraction should not assume the field names are fixed to these specific ones, as other field names can be used in other similar files.

The output should be a two-column TSV, with the field name as the first column and the field value as the second column. For example,

```
Name<TAB>Microsoft Word UNC Path Injector
...
```

Could anybody let me know the best `jq` way to achieve this? Thanks.

word_unc_injector.rb is at
https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/blob/master/modules/auxiliary/docx/word_unc_injector.rb

```
$ rb2json0.rb < word_unc_injector.rb | jq . # too long to include all output.
[
  "program",
  [
    [
      "command",
      [
        "@ident",
        "require",
        [
...
```

EDIT. The full solution of this problem may be complicated. But the first step might be to extract the part corresponding to `update_info`. Here is the relevant JSON fragment.

```
...
                        [    
                          "method_add_arg",
                          [    
                            "fcall",
                            [    
                              "@ident",
                              "update_info",
                              [    
                                24,  
                                10   
                              ]    
                            ]    
                          ],   
                          [    
                            "arg_paren",
                            [    
                              "args_add_block",
                              [    
                                [    
                                  "var_ref",
                                  [    
                                    "@ident",
                                    "info",
                                    [    
                                      24,  
                                      22   
                                    ]    
                                  ]    
                                ],   
                                [    
                                  "bare_assoc_hash",
                                  [    
                                    [    
                                      "assoc_new",
                                      [    
                                        "string_literal",
                                        [    
                                          "string_content",
                                          [    
                                            "@tstring_content",
                                            "Name",
...
```

Comment: The output may be too long to include, so it would be helpful if you could create a short but complete illustrative and informative example of the JSON that you want converted into a more useful form.

Comment: Could you download the file word_unc_injector.rb and use rb2json0.rb to generate the JSON file? The problem is the complexity. Any time when I simplify it, it is not complex any more.

Comment: It looks like you're asking a Ruby programmer to do the work for you, so you should probably at least add a "ruby" tag.  If you want help with jq, it would be a good idea to state the requirements from a JSON perspective, with a complete but short example.

Comment: No. This is a jq question. I have already converted the problem from ruby to jq. The description of the input has to be in terms of the original ruby file as the original ruby code is much more readable than the converted JSON file.

Answer (score 0):

The following illustrates how to convert the array-oriented JSON produced by rb2json0.rb to a more object-oriented JSON, in a way that you can query for `update_info@ident` in a straightforward way.

```
def objectify:
  if type == "array"
  then if length>=2 and (.[0]|type) == "string" and (.[1]|type) == "array"
       then  {(.[0]): ( .[1:] | map(objectify)) | objectify }
       elif length>=3 and .[0][0:1] == "@" and (.[1]|type) == "string"
       then  { (.[1] + .[0]): ( .[2:] | map(objectify)) | objectify }
       else map(objectify)
       end
  else . 
  end;
```

#### Illustrative query

Given the snippet shown, the following produces the output shown below:

```
objectify | .. | objects | .["update_info@ident"]? // empty
```

Output

```
[[24,10]]
```